# How do I check/change the text in a React button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, rxjs, conditional-statements

I have a react button and I want to change the text depending on what text is already displayed. How can I do this using a conditional statement?

I have the following code setup:

```
buttonClicked() {

}

create() {
  return (
    <button>X</button>
  );
}
```

Sorry if this is really simple, I searched for it and couldn't find anything, and I am very new to React.

Comment: Have you tried anything with regards to setting/controlling the state yet?

Comment: What has this got to do with RxJS?

Comment: Hey, helloworld12345: Here's an example of using state to change element's text, https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

useState in react and then a switch for the current value

```
export default function App() {
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("My Button");

  handleClick = () => {
    switch (buttonText) {
      case "My Button":
        setButtonText("My Button 1");
        break;
      case "My Button 1":
        setButtonText("My Button 2");
        break;
      case "My Button 2":
        setButtonText("Whoops");
        break;
      default:
        setButtonText("My Button");
        break;
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>{buttonText}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the button text using JS `QuerySelector`.

```js
buttonClicked() {
  const btn = document.querySelector("#myButton"); // get button elm by id
  const text = btn.textContent || btn.innerText; // get button text (the prop is browser-dependant)

  // change button text based on condition
  if (text === 'X') btn.innerHTML = 'button has X value';
  else btn.innerHTML = 'button has another value';
}

create() {
  return (
    <button id="myButton">X</button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Actually, the OP's question is mistitled.  They say "I want to CHANGE the text depending on what text is already displayed," I'll edit/update that now.

Comment: Thanks, @HoldOffHunger! I'll wait the OP to answer if he is using state or not.

Comment: Ah, I think it's that OP wants to check AND change the button text.  I think I only see a way to check the button text in your answer, I could be wrong, still early here.